# Problema con FPDF no guarda pdf en PYTHON (pyInstaller)

Tags: python, fpdf, pyinstaller

Me sucede algo muy extraño, tengo el siguiente código y funciona perfectamente en visual code, pero al querer convertirlo a .exe y realizar el pdf ya con el script 'compilado' no me genera nada, intente con fpdf2 pero tampoco, tengo otras funciones que exportan a csv o excel y esas no me generan ningún problema.
Alguien puede ayudarme ?

```
    def Exportar(self):
        path = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Exportar', self.comboBoxUsuario.currentText(), 'PDF(*.pdf)')
        if path[0] != '':

            Listaa = []

            for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                Texto1= self.tableWidget.item(i, 0).text()
                Texto2= self.tableWidget.item(i, 1).text()
                Texto3= self.tableWidget.item(i, 2).text()
                Texto4= self.tableWidget.item(i,3).text()
                Texto5= self.tableWidget.item(i, 4).text()
                Texto6= float(Credito) + float(Efectivo)
                Listaa.append([Texto1,Texto2,Texto3,Texto4,Texto5])

            pdf = FPDF(orientation = 'P', unit = 'mm', format='A4') 
            pdf.add_page()
            pdf.add_font(family='Montserrat',style='',fname='Montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf',uni=True)
            pdf.add_font(family='Montserrat',style='B',fname='Montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf',uni=True)
            pdf.set_top_margin(5)
            pdf.set_left_margin(5)
            pdf.set_right_margin(5)

            pdf.set_font('Montserrat', 'B', size = 20)
            pdf.set_fill_color(r=255,g=255,b=255) 
            pdf.set_text_color(r=0,g=0,b=0)


            for valor in Listaa:
                pdf.cell(w = 40, h = 10, txt = str(valor[0]), border = 0,align = 'C', fill = 1)
                pdf.cell(w = 40, h = 10, txt = str(valor[1]), border = 0,align = 'C', fill = 1)
                pdf.cell(w = 40, h = 10, txt = str(valor[2]), border = 0,align = 'C', fill = 1)
                pdf.cell(w = 40, h = 10, txt = str(valor[3]), border = 0,align = 'C', fill = 1)
                pdf.multi_cell(w = 40, h = 10, txt = str(valor[4]), border = 0,align = 'C', fill = 1)

            pdf.set_font('Montserrat', 'B', size = 15)
            pdf.set_fill_color(r=255,g=255,b=255)
            pdf.set_text_color(r=0,g=0,b=0)

            pdf.cell(w = 0, h = 10, txt = 'GENERAL: $ ' + str(Texto6), border = 0,align = 'R', fill = 1)
            
            pdf.output(path[0])
```

Comment: Python solo funcionara si la extensión es `algo.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Para que importe FPDF, debes de poner en la primera línea:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
```